# Are fetched, but not applied, values persisted across app launches in iOS Firebase remote config?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

When using Firebase Remote Config with the iOS SDK, do values returned from `remoteConfig.fetch()` persist across app launches? The docs say that applied values are persisted:

> If a value was fetched from the service and then activated, the app uses the fetched value. Activated parameter values are persistent.

[Remote Config Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters)

But I am interested if fetched values that have **not** been applied are persisted. I wasn't able to find any explicit documentation on that.

To clarify:

1. Call `fetch()` for new values, and wait for the call to return
2. Force quit app
3. Launch app
4. Call `activateFetched()`
5. Does my RemoteConfig now have the fetched values from the previous launch activated?

I've tested myself and seen that the values do persist across launches, but I don't want to be relying on undocumented behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetched values that are not applied are not ever used by the app.  A call to apply must occur in order for previously fetched values to take effect.  If never applied, then fetched values are never seen in the app, even across app restarts.

If you're asking that fetched values are stored persistently until applied, even across restarts, the answer to that is yes as well.

Comment: I'll update the question to be more clear, but I mean that if i then call `activateFetched()` on the second launch, are the previously fetched values applied

Comment: If you're asking that fetched values are stored persistently until applied, even across restarts, the answer to that is yes as well.